# Query in Postgres takes more time for later added data than earlier added data

Tags: sql, django, database, postgresql

I have an application where I have to filter a table and aggregate various values. Now the query performs fast if the data range filtered is part of earlier added rows and the query takes lot longer if the data range filtered is part of the later added rows.

This is the first query, filtering data with date_int between 43719 and 43726 . This query takes only 669ms

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "content_song"."title" AS Col1
>   FROM "tags_playlistentryviewership" INNER JOIN "content_playlistentry"
>   ON ("tags_playlistentryviewership"."playlist_entry_id" =
>   "content_playlistentry"."id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "content_song" ON
>   ("content_playlistentry"."song_id" = "content_song"."id") WHERE
>   (("tags_playlistentryviewership"."channel_id" =
>   '1ddc96bc-2f77-4293-b774-0018bc541044'::uuid OR
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."channel_id" =
>   '25260324-e79d-4e0b-b08b-f7ac9419024d'::uuid OR
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."channel_id" =
>   '25c29a3b-635d-4afc-b0ac-5373132f7ed8'::uuid OR
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."channel_id" =
>   '3af60df1-7d19-48eb-971e-162504e33b24'::uuid OR
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."channel_id" =
>   '783dbae0-cca5-4272-b101-7e10d4ce1f17'::uuid OR
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."channel_id" =
>   'b4f627c3-727b-40b6-bbe0-2501a8a30079'::uuid OR
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."channel_id" =
>   'c5933372-af36-406e-89e3-49d3e30bfa61'::uuid OR
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."channel_id" =
>   'c9a26012-f070-4637-a80f-947024856887'::uuid OR
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."channel_id" =
>   'f53781f4-7248-4cdc-a0c8-30fe691b9248'::uuid OR
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."channel_id" =
>   'fa2dfe7c-8218-4236-a70a-f76729e35f5e'::uuid) AND
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."target_group_id" =
>   '23f70629-ebb7-4f13-af5c-2ed26e0d0e31'::uuid AND
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."region_id" IN (SELECT U0."id" AS Col1
>   FROM "content_region" U0 INNER JOIN "content_region_portal_map" U1 ON
>   (U0."id" = U1."to_region_id") WHERE U1."from_region_id" =
>   'c8fd4db2-790a-4fa2-9a54-8f6cdf76da2f'::uuid) AND
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."date_int" >= 43719 AND
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."date_int" <= 43726)) subquery

While with all other filters remaining same but now querying data with date_int between 43806 and 43812 is given below. This query takes 11100 ms.

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "content_song"."title" AS Col1
>   FROM "tags_playlistentryviewership" INNER JOIN "content_playlistentry"
>   ON ("tags_playlistentryviewership"."playlist_entry_id" =
>   "content_playlistentry"."id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "content_song" ON
>   ("content_playlistentry"."song_id" = "content_song"."id") WHERE
>   (("tags_playlistentryviewership"."channel_id" =
>   '1ddc96bc-2f77-4293-b774-0018bc541044'::uuid OR
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."channel_id" =
>   '25260324-e79d-4e0b-b08b-f7ac9419024d'::uuid OR
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."channel_id" =
>   '25c29a3b-635d-4afc-b0ac-5373132f7ed8'::uuid OR
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."channel_id" =
>   '3af60df1-7d19-48eb-971e-162504e33b24'::uuid OR
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."channel_id" =
>   '783dbae0-cca5-4272-b101-7e10d4ce1f17'::uuid OR
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."channel_id" =
>   'b4f627c3-727b-40b6-bbe0-2501a8a30079'::uuid OR
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."channel_id" =
>   'c5933372-af36-406e-89e3-49d3e30bfa61'::uuid OR
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."channel_id" =
>   'c9a26012-f070-4637-a80f-947024856887'::uuid OR
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."channel_id" =
>   'f53781f4-7248-4cdc-a0c8-30fe691b9248'::uuid OR
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."channel_id" =
>   'fa2dfe7c-8218-4236-a70a-f76729e35f5e'::uuid) AND
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."target_group_id" =
>   '23f70629-ebb7-4f13-af5c-2ed26e0d0e31'::uuid AND
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."region_id" IN (SELECT U0."id" AS Col1
>   FROM "content_region" U0 INNER JOIN "content_region_portal_map" U1 ON
>   (U0."id" = U1."to_region_id") WHERE U1."from_region_id" =
>   'c8fd4db2-790a-4fa2-9a54-8f6cdf76da2f'::uuid) AND
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."date_int" >= 43806 AND
>   "tags_playlistentryviewership"."date_int" <= 43810)) subquery

I am not understanding why the query response time is so different and how to improve this.

Comment: Did you vacuum the table after the recent data was added?

Comment: No, I didn't run vacuum

Comment: If a VACUUM doesn't fix it, then please post an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) for each version of the query.  Preferably, turn track_io_timing on first if you can.  You need to be a superuser to do that.

Comment: AFter I ran Vacuum full. Now the query times are almost similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute [explain analyze](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) on both queries and see if their execution plans differ.
PostgreSQL includes quite good query planning system, but it can choose ineffective paths time to time.
With that information you would be able to decide what to do next.

Also, I'd recommend to check if you have indexes on all columns that you use in `where` and `join` statements.

And if you can change these queries, then you can remove unused subquery:

```
select count(distinct column) from ...
```